# Inject IHttpClientFactory into class that's in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently developing an ASP NET Core project with a linked API project, so we can have shared code between different projects. I'm wanting to inject an `IHttpClientFactory` into one of the classes in the API project, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to inject the factory or a way to create a client factory for the API itself?

Worst case, we can handle just a static `HttpClient` object and just use that in classes, but we'd prefer to use this method to have those instances managed cleanly.

Here's an example of the code we've tried.

```
services.AddHttpClient<Logger>(client =>
{
    /* Redacted */
});
```

```
public class Logger
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    public Logger(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

The `Logger` class is part of our API project.

Comment: Can you please explain _" but it doesn't seem to be working"_? And please add a [mre].

Comment: See if this helps: https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/03/06/using-dependency-injection-in-multiple-projects.html

Comment: Does `Logger` implement any interfaces? Is it registered somewhere additionally?

Comment: @GuruStron `Logger` does not implement any interfaces nor does it get registered anywhere. The methods in there are all static, so we can log from anywhere.

Comment: @BenjaminSims DI does not work well with statics. Actually some can argue that using statics beats the purpose of DI.

Comment: If the methods in Logger are all static....then what was the point of creating a constructor to receive an HttpClient? Static objects can't access instance fields, unless they create a reference to an instance. But with DI, you generally don't "new up" objects on the fly (except for perhaps "dumb" classes that just contain data, not logic). So, make your logger methods non-static, and anywhere that needs an instance of a logger should receive one via DI. Avoid static!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Logger` class you need to add it in the constructor. DI will resolve it for you.

```
public class Logger
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    public Logger(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {  
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("clientName")
    }
}
```

or don't create the `HttpClient` right away just save the `HttpClientFactory` and create the client when you are using it. The factory will manage the connections for you.

Comment: `AddHttpClient<Logger>` should add typed HttpClient so there should be no need resolving `IHttpClientFactory` directly.

Comment: I've tried this approach as well, and it didn't even hit the constructor.

Comment: if it's not hitting the constructor then you are instantiating the object yet. how do you intend to use it?